# What does "even" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The pass-through from weak sterling could thus be bigger than rules of thumb imply. The Bank of England’s latest inflation report already suggests that by 2017-18 inflation will be well above the 2% target, as commodity prices stop falling. **Even** this estimate may be conservative. Stock up on beer and ham before their prices rise, too.

(Is there anything wrong with the punctuation, I wonder?)

source: http://www.economist.com/news/britain/21707114-firms-may-struggle-absorb-extra-cost-pricier-imports-consumers-will-foot-bill-how

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/even. Check the first definition, last example. Or this https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/even adverb definition 1, second example.

Comment: I don't think they can help me, @JavaLatte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Even* has a couple of meanings, one of them means "same level as something else" ("even *with* X" or "X and Y are even"), and another is "not tilted" ("X is even").

An unrelated additional meaning, when used as an modifier/adverb, is hard to explain.  It's something like an intensifier.  Google's definition explains it well: "used to emphasize something surprising or extreme."  It's a lot like the word *only* in that it's position in a sentence is flexible and the meaning of the sentence changes depending on where it appears.

> I didn't even to go work today.  (Normally I go to work, but something surprising/extreme happened and I didn't go.)
>
> Even I don't know why he said that. (What is surprising/extreme is the fact that *I* don't know why.  Others may not know why but they aren't expected to know.)
>
> I don't even know why he said that. (I know this person well, but he said something surpring/extreme what he said doesn't make sense to me.)
>
> I don't know why he even said that. (Here, he probably said something he shouldn't.  *That* - the thing he said - is the surprising/extreme thing.)
>
> I don't know why he said even that. (Here, the surprising/extreme thing is not *what* he said, but the fact he said "that".  )
>
> I don't know why he said that even. (Can mean the same as above, or can mean the whole phrase "I don't know why he said that" is surprising/extreme.  Someone is asking a speaker about events, the listener has said something does not make sense or is extreme, and the speaker is acknowledging that to the listener.)

So, with this:

> England’s latest inflation report already suggests that by 2017-18 inflation will be well above the 2% target, as commodity prices stop falling. Even this estimate may be conservative.

"This estimate" is extreme/surprising.  What they are saying is that whatever amount the estimate is, it's already breaking limits, but their estimate will actually be a "lowest possible" change instead of a "highest possible" change.

---

For completeness, a phrase you might hear is *even though X*, which is equivalent to *despite X*.

Answer (score 2):

***[Even](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/even)*** in the context is used to underline the fact that,  surprisingly,  also the 2% plus  inflation assumption may be conservative:

> - (***intensifier;*** used to suggest that the content of a statement is unexpected or paradoxical): even an idiot can do that.

Collins Dictionary